# Storing references to class members. Is there a nice solution?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I'm trying design a set a classes to store / access / analyse my data but I'm not sure how they should fit together.

### Background

My (simplified) data is in the form of "events" which can be represented like this:

```
//Representation of my data
class Event
{
private:
vector<track> tracks_;
vector<cluster> clusters_;
};
```

where `track` and `cluster` have functions like `get_track_time()` or `get_cluster_size()`.

I have multiple algorithms for selecting the "best" track and cluster which I want to make available to more complicated functions. I want to store this selection so that it only has to be computed once for each event.

### Question

How do I store the "best" track? Below is my code storing a pointer/reference to a private member in an external object. This breaks encapsulation but I can't store a pointer inside the 'Event' class because there could be more than one definition of "best" at any one time. Do I just have to accept pointers/references to private members or is there a better way to arrange things?

### My code

I was thinking of representing them with function objects, resulting in this:

```
//Interface for selecting a particular track
class BestTrack
{
public:
virtual void new_event(const Event& e) = 0;
virtual const& track get_track(const Event& e) = 0;
virtual ~BestTrack();
    };

//Sample implementation of track selection
class ABestTrack : public BestTrack
    {
    public:
    void new_event(const Event& e )
        { ..implementation sets cached_track... }

    const& track get_track()
    { return *cached_track; }


private:
track * cached_track; //I think this would have to be a pointer not a reference
};
```

which would be used by my analysis objects:

```
//Some complicated analysis object
class MyAnalysis
{
public:
MyAnalysis( BestTrack * bt );
void DoAnalysis( const Event& e )
{
//get the best track
auto best_track  = bt( e );
...implementation...
}
private:
BestTrack* bt;
};
```

So that finally I can do

```
int main()
{

//Create all my "best" selection algorithms
ABestTrack a_best_track;
BBestTrack b_best_track;
CBestCluster c_best_cluster;
DBestCluster d_best_cluster;

//Mix and match algorithms
MyAnalysis analysis_1( &a_best_track, &d_best_cluster );
MyAnalysis analysis_2( &b_best_track, &c_best_cluster );


  //In reality the rest of this would be in a loop
for ( something )
{
    const Event event;
    a_best_track.new_event( event);
    b_best_track.new_event( event);
    c_best_cluster.new_event( event);
    d_best_cluster.new_event( event);


    //Each analysis gets a reference to it's own definition of the "best" track
    analysis_1.DoAnalysis( event );
    analysis_2.DoAnalysis( event );

}
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of the BestTrack objects.  Is there a performance hit for just asking the Event for the BestTrack?  It seems the simplest solution would be just add a member function to event that returns the best track of the moment.

Comment: Instead of storing a pointer to the best track in the ABestTrack you might want to make a copy.  After that object is created is it possible that in the future it may not be the best track anymore or it may have been removed?

Comment: The problem is that there can be more than one definition of best track at one time: for the same event, different algorithms will get a different answer so there is no single best track of the moment.

Comment: It seems to me the analysis functions could be standalone (or static member) functions that compare the "goodness" of any two given tracks.  At that point, any sorted collection would be able to give you as many "best" tracks as you want, and you wouldn't need a `BestTrack` class at all.

Comment: I agree making a copy of the track would work. A given algorithm's decision will not change until it receives a new event. I thought a pointer would be more efficient than a copy but I admit I don't know if would be a bottle neck.

Comment: @cHao but "goodness" is not universal - it depends on the algorithm so there is no single sorted order.

Comment: @paco_uk: That's why you have a function/functor for each algorithm.  Say you have a `FirstFit`, where `FirstFit(a, b)`, returns true if track `a` is better than track `b`.  Iterating through a `set<track, FirstFit>` would give you a list of tracks in ascending order of "goodness" from FirstFit's point of view.

Comment: I would copy the value instead of the pointer to maintain separation of the `BestTrack` from it's data source.  If the source is changed or removed you will get access violations and it may be very hard to track down.

Comment: We seem to be converging on copying the object. As I understand it,  the set solution proposed by @cHao also requires copying.

Comment: @paco_uk: Copying would be simpler, but it depends on what you're doing with the objects.  A copy of course will be detached from the original.  I do like the idea of referring to the tracks by index rather than by pointer.  Possibly even better, have a class that contains nothing but a reference/pointer to the event, and an index.  It'd basically work kinda like an iterator, pretending to be a pointer to a track...but you wouldn't run into annoying issues with pointers being invalidated unless the event dies.

Comment: Are the events, tracks, and clusters conceptually supposed to be a value-type or reference-type? If it's meant to be value-type, then you should make them immutable and copying would be natural (because you don't want to invalidate the BestTrack's pointer if Event is freed). The other alternative if they're meant to be value type, is to have events contains pointers to immutable tracks and clusters and you can avoid copying, but that is difficult to manage without automatic garbage collection.

Comment: If they're meant to be reference-type, then the lifetime of tracks and clusters shouldn't be tied to the lifetime of events, so you should probably have events contains only pointers to tracks and clusters. In the case of reference type, tasks and clusters have it's own identity separate from event.

Comment: @LieRyan If I have understood the definitions, I am dealing with value-type objects. I think part of my problem is that in practice I know that in my current design there is no plan to free Event while a BestTrack has stored a pointer so a copy feels like extra work even though it is the natural thing to do. I'll probably go with the indexing idea to avoid both dangling pointers and extra copies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to internal members can be ok, I mean encapsulation is there to help you , not make your life harder. Piles of data don't need encapsulation as much as live objects do. When you have things that look/behave like data, it can be efficient to treat them that way. Thoughts:

- Const pointers are better than not const. (not const really breaks encapulation)
- Can you return value objects to be held by the interested parties, rather than ref/pointer?
- Might your pointers be invalidated? eg by a re-allocation of the vector?
- You could return a Event subclass, that essentially contains a index into the vectors, and that Event provides a decoding function for (this would help with encapsulation and pointer invalidation too)

Comment: Good points. I guess I'll have to check the cost of returning the value object. I hadn't thought of the index - I'll have a think about it. In my case there is no risk of invalidation - the event is const.

Comment: @paco_uk: even if the event is const, the pointer can still be invalidated if event is freed. Unless you can make sure that BestTrack is invalidated if the Event is invalidated, then you should really be careful with having pointers to the tracks and clusters inside events.

Comment: So, const is good, in that it means your vectors wont invalidate pointers merely by growing, but pointers still create a life-time issue - they are only valid while the Event they came from is valid. That is a common experience for people who use iterators, so it's not terrible, but iterator invalidation is a common source of errors, so you need to know you are creating that source of error here with pointer invalidation.

Comment: Adding a index/lookup widget for the event makes the lifetime thing a little more explicit, since you need the Event to use the "index", but there is the effort trade-off.